# Excel formula treating numbers in the same cell differently

Tags: excel

G'day, 
I have never really used excel formulas before but need to convert a sexigismal long/lat point to decimal degrees. This is easy enough, e.g.,

if Easting = 29 44.135' => 29 + (44.135*1/60) => 29.73558333 E

The problem I have is that the 29 44.135 is in one cell and I don't know how to individually specify the separate parts of this number to write out the above formula.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance!

Regards,
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the two parts are separated by a single space:

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1) + MID(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1)-1)*1/60
```

Comment: @Tim Williams - the -1 towards the end of the formula is actually making the result slightly incorrect, that means that the 5 in 44.135 is excluded so you get result 29.73550000 rather than 29.73558333. Either remove -1 or use this shorter version =LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)+REPLACE(A1,1,FIND(" ",A1),"")/60......or entirely different approach.....=DOLLARDE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")," ","."),60)

Comment: @barry - did you include the ' at the end of the value?  I had it there when I tested and that's what the -1 was for.  Maybe I miscalculated...

Comment: @Tim - no I didn't, apologies [D'oh!], I didn't consider that - I read `the 29 44.135 is in one cell` [without '] but I see that it also says `Easting = 29 44.135'`